# Passing char pointer to another function: blank value. c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following very simple program.

```
int modify(char * v){
  v = "123" ;

  return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
char *test = new char[10];
  modify(test);
  std::cout << test;
  return 0;

}
```

I know I can just print out "123", but I deliberately wrote it that way to learn about how pointers work. However, "123" is not printed. How should I correctly pass the pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remember that in C++ arguments are by default passed *by value*, meaning that in the function you have copies., and modifying a copy will not change the original.

If you want to change the pointer to point to something else you need to pass it *by reference*. However, in this case it will cause other problems, as you then loose the original pointer.

So the solution is to either use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) passed by reference, or by using [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) top copy into the destination memory area (but if you use `strcpy` you have to take care to not write beyond the allocated memory).

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside modify `strcpy(v, "123")`

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

Your `modify()` function actually changes nothing:

```
int modify(char * v) {
  v = "123"; // overwrites the parameter value copy on the stack
             // with a char[] literal pointer
  return 0;
}
```

You need to copy from the literal to the pointer:

```
int modify(char* v) {
  strcpy(v,"123");
  return 0;
}
```

You do not free the allocated memory, which may lead to memory leaks in other situations

```
int main (int argc, char** argv){
char *test = new char[10];
  modify(test);
  std::cout << test;
  delete [] char; // <<< Note
  return 0;    
}
```

As Joachim Pileborg already mentioned the most approriate solution for c++ would be to use a `std::string` instead of `char*`.